# Slow script performance when browser is minimized

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, throttling

Im running a javascript in the Chrome DevTools console, but when I minimize the browser the script runs 10x(?) slower.

I searched on `chrome://flags` for `throttling` and it returned:

[image]

I have changed `Throttle Javascript timers in background.` from `default` to `disabled`, but it continues running the script very slowly, what else I'm missing?

Comment: You're probably not missing anything. The OS or the browser itself will likely do something like that for performance... Use node if you want to run a script headless